# move files in a hadoop dir with specified number of files

Tags: hadoop

I wish to move files in a hadoop dir in a timely manner.

The hadoop dir contains 1000 files with the same extension. I wish to move 100 of them every 10 minutes. I can setup a cron job to move the files every 10 minutes but I don't know how to specify the number of files to be moved.

```
hdfs dfs -ls /src/ | tail -100 | xargs hdfs dfs -mv {} / dest/
```

Any command to use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mv like this: mv -t target file1 file2 file3 ...

```
ls | head -n 100 | xargs mv -t destination
```

Comment: Kind of missing the HDPS part here...

Answer (score 1):

What about using a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

Source="/where/they/are/now/*"
Destination="/where/they/will/go"

while true; do
  count=0
  for file in $Source; do
    if [ $((count++)) -eq 100 ];then
      break
    else mv "$file" "$Destination"
    fi
  done
  sleep 10m
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future generations:

```
hdfs dfs -mv `hdfs dfs -ls -C {your_src_hdfs_path} | head -{number_of_files}` {your_dest_hdfs_path}
```